# Convert XML Soap using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have a soap request and i need to transform this.

the soap xml:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getReservationsResponse xmlns:ns="http://webService/xsd">
         <ns:return>
            <resid xmlns="http://reservation.proxsafe.deister.de/xsd">100</resid>
            <active xmlns="http://reservation.proxsafe.deister.de/xsd">true</active>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:getReservationsResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

First i use a xsl  to strip all of the soap

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- remove all elements in the soapenv namespace -->
<xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for the remaining elements (i.e. elements in the default namespace) ... -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- ... create a new element with similar name in no-namespace -->
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But now i need to rename 'getReservationsResponse' to Data and
return to Object
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="http://webService/xsd"
exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- remove all elements in the soapenv namespace -->
<xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for the remaining elements (i.e. elements in the default namespace) ... -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- ... create a new element with similar name in no-namespace -->
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:getReservationsResponse">
    <Data>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:return">
    <Object>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Object>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ok, but i need the following output.
 <Object Type="Vendor" Action="InsertOrUpdate">
     <Property Name="ExternalId" Value="{Resid}" />
     <Property Name="Activated" Value="Active" />

    </Object>

Comment: These can be achieved by using templates in your code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can add few templates to your xslt.

in your namespace declaration update

```
**xmlns:ns="http://webService/xsd"
xmlns:ns1="http://reservation.proxsafe.deister.de/xsd"**
exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv **ns ns1**"
```

and add templates

```
<xsl:template match="ns:getReservationsResponse">
    <Data>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="ns:return">
    <Object>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:resid">
    <Property Name="ExternalId" Value="{.}" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:active">
    <Property Name="Activated" Value="{.}" />
</xsl:template>
```

test [link](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6M) here.